# Finding related words/concepts with PHP

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, tagging

I have a project that I am working on it, need something like this:

When someone writes down a word, The system will find a few other words related to the first word.

For example, if someone writes down "Manchester United", system will automatically say "football", "soccer", "premier league", "goal", "match" eg.

Have you got any idea how can i do that? Where can i get those information?

Comment: Google.  I would run the query through Google and see what the most common words are in the results.

Comment: @Sercan: how's this going for you?

Comment: @Cpfohl I have not got enough programming knowledge to use Google or work with huge amount of data using a public dictionary. I, simply, created a database with 4 columns (id, keyword, related1, related2) and inserted some data manually about the topic. (Nearly 1000 rows, I know it is dumb way to do it but did not have any other choice.) Now, my users are able to add their related words if they want. I did sth for the project to work, but i know that is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at Princeton's WordNet. http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

It should be able to give all sorts of similar words just be navigating the graph they provide.

**[EDIT]**
Looks like you need something more robust than looking it up in WordNet.

Try to write a recommender system (see the comment for the Wikipedia page overviewing that) that takes into account whatever data your user willingly allows you to pry out of their hand and several features, including the "wordnet feature" which can be translated into english from other languages.

Be sure to include user's language as a feature, and if possible choose an algorithm that can determine how reliable wordnet is for that language.

Comment: Good idea but, I am trying to do this system for another language, not English. Princeton's WordNet is only works for English.

Comment: Hmm, should've mentioned that...my best suggestion is that you use another tool to translate the word into English and use the tool.  Otherwise you'll have to use some sort of clustering algorithm and you'd need a huge amount of data.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) I guess, I will need a huge amount of data as you said, in ALL cases :/ Have you got any idea how UPlanMe works? It takes your facebook account and after checking and analyzing your likes and other stuff, It finds topics tailored within your interests.